# Let f be a real valued continuous function such that for all real x and for all t≥0, f(x)=f(x•e^t). Show that f is a constant function.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, solution-verification

My approach to solving the problem stated in the title is as follows:

f(x)=f(x•e^t)=y(say)

Differentiating both sides w.r.t x, I got

f'(x)=e^t•f'(x•e^t)

This implies

e^t=1 [since f(x)=f(x•e^t) implies their derivatives are equal as well]

The above equation holds true for the case when t=0, which would trivially mean f(x)=f(x). To explain the above equality for all t≥0,

f'(x)=f'(x•e^t)=0, which means f is a constant function.

However, **I'm concerned with the rationality of my last step, which makes me doubt my approach altogether. Can anyone explain if my approach is correct?**

My background: High school level calculus. Once again, apologies for not using MathJax :)

Comment: This is really hard to read. Please use MathJax.

Comment: @copper.hat Wish I could, but I still find MathJax too complex. I'll wait for someone to fix it.

Comment: Your argument is correct  though. You conclude: $e^t=1$ for all $t\geq 0$ if not $f'\equiv 0$: Contradiction! thus $f'\equiv 0$.. and You are done. For further questions though [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might be helpful to You

Comment: What makes you think $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: @MananJain: It is not broken, and Latex is fairly standard.

Comment: Thanks! I (naïvely) didn't consider the possibility of a contradiction earlier.

Comment: @almagest True, I assumed differentiability vaguely(maybe just because I have to prove that f is constant, I know that I can't assume what I have prove). Perhaps that poses one more problem to my approach :/

Comment: @almagest 's comment is to be thought about, if $f$ is not differentiable the argument doesn't work this way

Comment: This is all that is there to the question. I have no idea how to go about the differentiability aspect of f.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily differentiable. Taking $x = ye^{-t}$, get $f(ye^{-t})=f(y)$ for every $t\geq 0, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Now taking the limit as $t \to \infty$ of both sides. This gives the result by continuity of $f$

Answer (score 1):

For the function $e^x$ maps $[0,\infty]$ onto $[1,\infty]$. So given any $0<x<y$ we can choose $t$ such that $y=xe^t$ and then we have $f(x)=f(y)$. In other words we have $f(x)$ equals some constant $c_1$ on the positive reals (either $x=y,x<y$ or $y<x$).

Similarly, $f(x)$ is constant $c_2$ on the negative reals. But we are told it is continuous, so we must have $c_1=f(0)=c_2$ and $f$ is constant on the reals.

Comment: My bad, but can you elaborate the reasoning a little bit after f(x)=f(y)? I don't understand why f(x) should be some constant c1 on positive reals

Comment: @MananJain  Ok. Let's start with $x>1$. We can find $t>0$ such that $x=e^t$, so $f(1)=f(1\cdot e^y)=f(x)$. Now take $0<x<1$ we can now find $t>0$ such that $e^t=1/x$, So $f(x)=f(xe^t)=f(1)$. So we can take $c_1=f(1)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!